# What's "Another Way In"?

Tags: jetpack-joyride

There's a new achievement and I'm stumped as to how to get it:

> Start a game without breaking the laboratory wall

I assume it has something to do with the new Gadgets but none of them sound like they'd help. How do I get this achievement?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to get all the way up to the *free ride* gadget,then keep playing games until you get the **teleporter vehicle** then you can do the achievement.

Comment: While it sounds like there are new additions to Jetpack Joyride, I can say from past experience in previous versions that if you win a head start in the last spin, you won't break the wall when you start the game with that head start.

Answer (score 7):

The head start does not trigger the achievement.  Like Arremer said, you have to equip the Free Ride gadget and then randomly get the Teleproter Vehicle when you start.